# Using forever with Node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a few, possibly trivial, questions with using forever with Node.js. From what I have read, forever can be used programatically and it maintains a list with all the scripts that use forever. When that process dies, it automatically spawns a new one until it is stopped.

However, my question is, how does forever do this? Does it add these scripts to be started on boot as well?

Comment: Thank you @Dan Davies Brackett

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use forever programatically like this:

Using an instance of Forever inside a node.js script:

```
var forever = require('forever-monitor');

  var child = new (forever.Monitor)('your-filename.js', {
    max: 3,
    silent: true,
    options: []
  });

  child.on('exit', function () {
    console.log('your-filename.js has exited after 3 restarts');
  });

  child.start();
```

You should take a minute and read over the options available in the excellent documentation for Forever in [the README.md](https://github.com/indexzero/forever)

You have a number of events that can be listened for in Forever as well:

- error   [err]:                    Raised when an error occurs
- start   [process, fvrFile, data]: Raise when the target script is first started.
- stop    [process]:                Raised when the target script is stopped by the user
- save    [path, data]:             Raised when the target Monitor saves the pid information to disk.
- restart [forever]:                Raised each time the target script is restarted
- exit    [forever]:                Raised when the target script actually exits (permenantly).
- stdout  [data]:                   Raised when data is received from the child process' stdout
- stderr  [data]:                   Raised when data is received from the child process' stderr

It does this by attaching event listeners to the script you're trying to run and handling them in a graceful manner.

[The code](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever/blob/master/lib/forever.js) is pretty well documented if you want to take a look at exactly how it does it.

You should also read this [excellent tutorial](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever) on how to keep a process running forever.

As for the second question: No, it does not add it to start at boot. For that, you'd need to add it as an [upstart job](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) or use something like [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) to monitor and start it. For that, you should take a look at [Deploying Node.js with Upstart and Monit](http://howtonode.org/deploying-node-upstart-monit). It's a great tutorial.

Comment: The second half of your answer is exactly what I was looking for. I wasn't sure if that's what I had to do, so thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad I could help. Definitely read that tutorial on deploying node. I've used that method with a few tweaks very successfully in several past projects.

Comment: I had already come across the forever page on github, the upstart and monit tutorial, I will indeed read, now. Thanks

Comment: @slickplaid  Can you plz explain what the code does? because I want to restart my node.js script/server programmatically each time server crashes or the site goes down. How can I handle that programmatically to auto restart my script if it dies or if the site is not giving 200 OK ?

Answer (score 5):

This is an old post, but I stumbled across this on Google - its a little out of date, as forever branched the command line version from the programatic version. You need to use [forever-monitor](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever-monitor) instead of [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever). The example code should now be;

```
 var forever = require('forever-monitor');

  var child = new (forever.Monitor)('your-filename.js', {
    max: 3,
    silent: true,
    options: []
  });

  child.on('exit', function () {
    console.log('your-filename.js has exited after 3 restarts');
  });

  child.start();
```

I tried to suggest an edit to the original answer, but the powers that be rejected it. Figured I could spare some others the time it took me to figure out why the example code doesn't work :-)

Comment: Can you explain what the code does? because I want to restart my node.js script/server programmatically each time server crashes or the site goes down. How can I handle that programmatically to auto restart my script if it dies ?

Comment: @Faizan I'd recommend using forever from the command line instead of in code. If the server reboots, you can add a '@reboot' entry into a crontab to fire it up again. Also pm2 is worth a look too.