# forever does not start on server reboot

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, reboot, forever

I have added some processes to forever (`forever start script.js`) but when server reboot forever list is empty and of course none of them was started. Any idea to fix this because I thought **forever** was made to run for ever...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524716/using-forever-with-node-js Selected answer answers it.

Comment: well, I'm not using it programmatically...I've Balloons.IO installed and just want it to keep running

Comment: the related anwser @epascarello provided does answer your question (last paragraph of accepted answer) or you you can just start forever from /etc/rc.local

Comment: +1! good idea! can you write a reply below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to start forever from /etc/rc.local.  There are more complete ways to do this so you can start/stop/etc... or use something like monit (but this duplicates what forever does).

You also have to consider running forever with a user that is not root.

start_forever.sh

```
cd /absolute/path/to/project
/absolute/path/to/forever -m 5 examples/error-on-timer.js&
```

then in /etc/rc.local

```
sudo -u SOME_USER /absolute/path/to/start_forever.sh
```

Comment: I fundamentally disagree with "just add it to /etc/rc.local" for someone who looks like they don't understand why a non-service app doesn't restart on reboot. I recommend the use of tools like Monit to add this startup/shutdown behavior.

Comment: monit is certainly a better overall solution, and would be recommended on a prod system.  If you use monit, you would not really need forever :)

Comment: try pm2 https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2 MUCH better than forever and way easier than monit.